# Keras custom layer on ragged tensor to reduce dimensionallity

Tags: tensorflow, keras, ragged

I'm trying to write a custom layer that will handle variable-length vectors, and reduce them to the same length vector. 
The length is known in advance because the reason for the variable lengths is that I have several different data types that I encode using a different number of features. 
In a sense, it is similar to Embedding only for numerical values.
I've tried using padding, but the results were bad, so I'm trying this approach instead.

So, for example let's say I have 3 data types, which I encode with 3, 4, 6 length vectors.

```
arr = [
    # example one (data type 1 [len()==3], datat type 3[len()==6]) - force values as floats
    [[1.0,2.0,3],[1,2,3,4,5,6]],
    # example two (data type 2 [len()==4], datat type 3len()==6]) - force values as floats
    [[1.0,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5,6]],
]
```

I tried implementing a custom layer like:

```
class DimensionReducer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, output_dim, expected_lengths):
        super(DimensionReducer, self).__init__()
        self._supports_ragged_inputs = True
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        for l in expected_lengths:
            setattr(self,f'w_{l}', self.add_weight(shape=(l, self.output_dim),initializer='random_normal',trainable=True))
            setattr(self, f'b_{l}',self.add_weight(shape=(self.output_dim,), initializer='random_normal',trainable=True))

    def call(self, inputs):
        print(inputs.shape)

        # batch
        if len(inputs.shape) == 3:
            print("batch")
            result = []
            for i,x in enumerate(inputs):
                _result = []
                for v in x:
                    l = len(v)
                    print(l)
                    print(v)
                    w = getattr(self, f'w_{l}')
                    b = getattr(self, f'b_{l}')
                    out = tf.matmul([v],w) + b
                    _result.append(out)

                result.append(tf.concat(_result, 0))
            r = tf.stack(result)
            print("batch output:",r.shape)
            return r
```

Which seems to be working when called directly:

```
dim = DimensionReducer(3, [3,4,6])
dim(tf.ragged.constant(arr))
```

But when I try to incorporate it into a model, it fails:

```
import tensorflow as tf

val_ragged = tf.ragged.constant(arr)

inputs_ragged = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,None), ragged=True)
outputs_ragged = DimensionReducer(3, [3,4,6])(inputs_ragged)
model_ragged = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs_ragged, outputs=outputs_ragged)

# this one with RaggedTensor doesn't
print(model_ragged(val_ragged))
```

With

```
AttributeError: 'DimensionReducer' object has no attribute 'w_Tensor("dimension_reducer_98/strided_slice:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)'
```

I'm not sure how am I to implement such a layer, or what I'm doing wrong.